# put year in brackets by replace () Method

Tags: javascript, replace

I have an input of this type, for example:

```
Star Wars 1977
```

the output should be:

```
Star Wars (1977)
```

how do I get it using the replace() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to match a year, then replace it:

```js
var str = "Star Wars 1977";
str = str.replace(/(\d{4})/, '($1)');  // $1 is the first match, which is the year
console.log(str);
```

If you're dealing with movies, there are those that have years in their titles, so, to not match the year in the title, you can capture the year at the end of the string only:

```js
var str = "2001: A Space Odyssey 1968";
str = str.replace(/(\d{4})$/, '($1)');  // $1 is the first match, which is the year
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Be aware that this may have a strange effect on movies with a year in their title, such as `2001: A Space Odyssey`. You can reduce it by forcing the regex to match at the end of the string: `/(\d{4})$/`

Comment: @DuncanThacker How is it that while I was writing the update about this issue and using the exact movie you used as an example, you were writing this too? Wow.

Comment: @DuncanThacker Totally.

Answer (score 0):

Or... if you know what you want to replace:

`'Star Wars 1977'.replace('1977','($&)')`

I just thought I'd mention this (even though regex are the way to go) as I found out about normal string replace tokens accidentally (actually via a bug ;) ).